# Param is missing or value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, input

I have a little problem on Rails. When the user Upload a post without File in my file field I have a type error:
param is missing or the value is empty: video

However I have a "validates" in my model which should verify this so I do not understand very well.

New code :

Form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@video, html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>
    <div class="drop animated">
      <div class="box" id="Box">
        <%= f.label 'Upload Your Video', class:'label1', for:'fileUpload'  %>
        <%= f.label 'mp4 mp3 amv avi mkv', class:'label2', for:'fileUpload' %>
        <%= f.file_field :video, id:'fileUpload', style:'opacity:0;position:absolute;', required: true  %>
        <%= f.label 'Choose your file', for:'fileUpload', class:'btn-hover color-1 flex' %>
      </div>
      <div class="uploader" id="Uploader" style="opacity:1;">
        <%= f.button :submit, 'Upload', class:'btn btn-primary' %>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Model:

```
class Video < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :video, VideoUploader

  validates :video, presence: true


end
```

Controller:

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_video, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /videos
  # GET /videos.json
  def index
    @videos = Video.all
  end

  # GET /videos/1
  # GET /videos/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /videos/new
  def new
    @video = Video.new
  end

  # GET /videos/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /videos
  # POST /videos.json
  def create
    @video = Video.new(video_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @video.save
        format.html { redirect_to @video, notice: 'Video was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @video }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @video.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /videos/1
  # PATCH/PUT /videos/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @video.update(video_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @video, notice: 'Video was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @video }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @video.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /videos/1
  # DELETE /videos/1.json
  def destroy
    @video.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to videos_url, notice: 'Video was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_video
      @video = Video.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def video_params
      params.require(:video).permit(:video)
    end
end
```

Error:

```
Started POST "/videos" for ::1 at 2020-07-07 17:41:48 +0200
Processing by VideosController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"pv96ZVL2HWTu0vJSzrPBtspbXcsA2HZYG3f9Jk7RUXPEg8qJI86et4NpaA7Mlf+EljBjxe9eaK3gaZXt/ib77w==", "commit"=>"Upload"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


  
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: video):
  
app/controllers/videos_controller.rb:72:in `video_params'
app/controllers/videos_controller.rb:27:in `create'
```

Html Version :

```
 <form class="simple_form form-horizontal" id="new_video" novalidate="novalidate" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/videos" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="AmgYrn45aZ1hndJ88jh9ToTIumfnaHCWcxynOMp9kJ2DMTTY4UrYBJS9OJ5E4GgPEFXDlfLBtm/J1lOESw3HQQ==" />
  
  
    <div class="drop animated">
      <div class="box" id="Box">
        <label class="string optional label1" for="fileUpload">Upload your Video</label>
        <label class="string optional label2" for="fileUpload">mp4 mp3 amv avi mkv</label>
        <input id="fileUpload" style="opacity:0;position:absolute;" required="required" type="file" name="video[video]" />
        <label for="fileUpload" class="string optional btn-hover color-1 flex">Choose your file</label>
      </div>
      <div class="uploader" id="Uploader" style="opacity:1;">
        <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Upload" class="btn btn btn-primary" data-disable-with="Upload" />
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I update my code for more details.

Comment: Can you make your question more clear? Are you asking even if you added video validates in your model, why the user can still submit the form without filling the file field?

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely what I would like to know.Sorry if its not clear..

Comment: `validates` works on server side, not client side. If you want to validate frontend input fields, you can write javascript code to do that. Or in your case, just add `required` option to your file_field.

Comment: I already tested but it gave me the same error.  And in an old project I do not remember having to make a script js the validates was enough.

Comment: what's the name of your model? Through your `video_params`, it should be `Video`, right?

Comment: The name of my model is video.rb and my controller videos_controller.rb. Bytheway i'm using CarrierWave if that can help you.

Comment: The error message seems not directly related to validation, it may be caused by some wrong setup. could you post more code? Your `form`, your `model`, and your `controller`

Comment: I have update my code above.

Comment: Thanks for updating code. What's the log in your console when the error happens?

Comment: I put it above :)

Comment: Through the error message, it seems there is no form data submitted. Which *form helper* are you using? `form_for`?

Comment: I use simple_form_for

Comment: can you paste the whole form, I mean the whole form block starts with `simple_form_for`

Comment: Yep. Its done I update it

Comment: It seems, with `simple_form_for`, the way to create a file input html tag is to use `f.input  :video,  as: :file`.

Comment: Yes I have already tested but I still have the same error..

Comment: You can inspect the generated html using developer tool of the browser, what's the generated `form` html?

Comment: Yep. Its done I update it

Comment: the form has a `novalidate="novalidate"` option, which mean don't validate the form before submit. So, it by pass the required option of file input. try `<%= simple_form_for(@video, html: {class: 'form-horizontal', novalidate: false}) do |f| %>`

Comment: Thank you ! It' work ! Thanks for spending your time on my problem. I appreciate thank you.

Comment: You're welcome !